# OpenProcessToken fails after ImpersonateLoggedOnUser

Tags: c++, windows, privileges

I have a service that is impersonating a user. The service is running as Local System. The user is a local administrator and domain administrator. After impersonation, it's necessary for me to adjust the token privileges of the process. I hoped to do it using `OpenProcessToken` and then `AdjustTokenPrivileges` on the returned token handle.

After calling `LogonUser` and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` the following call is failing with access denied.

```
HANDLE hToken;
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
{
      Log("Error=%d", GetLastError());
}
```

I'm logging on the user using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` and `LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT`.

Adjusting the same privilege on the user token succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-part answer, depending on what you are trying to do:

1) If you want to adjust the privileges for the impersonation token, you need to use the OpenThreadToken function, not OpenProcessToken.  Impersonation affects the thread, not the process as a whole.  Try this:

```
OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, TRUE, &hToken)
```

2) If you really did want to adjust the privileges for the process token, you should probably do this at a point when you are not impersonating the client.  You can turn impersonation on and off as necessary.